# Regex URL redirect adding a slug except when that slug exists

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I am trying to use a hosting level regex redirect through Kinsta, this is a wordpress site, I want to redirect all traffic from a certain country to their specific version of the site. I am trying to redirect any and all pages except for any urls that contain 'wp-admin' (so that I can access the WP backend normally), or any that already contain the country code in the slug. Currently it is redirecting even if the country slug is there which results in 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'.

As an example I am trying to redirect Canadian users to rewrite the url to include '/en-ca/' and keep the page they were already visiting.
For example I do want to redirect these:

```
https://example.com/about ->  https://example.com/en-ca/about
https://example.com/ ->  https://example.com/en-ca/
https://example.com/shop/products ->  https://example.com/en-ca/shop/products
```

But I want to exclude redirecting on these:

```
https://example.com/wp-admin/pages
https://example.com/en-ca
https://example.com/en-ca/shop/products
```

A few of the different regex functions I've tried include

```
^/((?!(en-ca|wp-admin))(.*))
^\/(?!(en-ca|wp-admin))(.*)\/?
^\/(?!en-ca)^\/(.*)
^/!?(en-ca|wp-admin)(.*)
```

with each of these redirecting to `/en-ca/$1` or `/en-ca/$2` This is working for excluding the wp-admin but doesn't seem to be catching the `en-ca` correctly and results in infinite redirect error, a 404, or a situation where the url gets many `/en-ca/` slugs being added.

Any insight on why this regex redirect isn't working in this case and what I need to add to get it working would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use substitutions with a negative lookahead:

```
(\.[a-z]+)\/(?!wp-admin|en-ca)([\/\w-]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hvKa6G/1

If your urls have specific requirements, please adjust to include. I inferred some from your post.